# Get first n elements from sortedmap

Tags: groovy, treemap

I've tried to store frequencies of string in a TreeMap so that I can get the most frequently used strings of, say, a specific user.
Now what I want to do is to write a method to return me the first n items(top frequently used) from the sorted map.

```
public TreeMap<String,Integer> getKeywords(int n){
     //Can check if sorted for efficiency!

    println keywords.size();
    keywords=keywords.sort{a,b->
        //sort the map desc by value
        b.value <=> a.value;
    }
    TreeMap<String,Integer> result=new TreeMap<>();
    //need to fill result with first n elements from keywords
    return result;
}
```

I've tried several ways like using `.each()` on keywords or iterate through its keySet, yet none preserves its original order, and I ended up getting result unsorted.
Help & hints are appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Groovy, so I can only comment on Java.

A `TreeMap` keeps the entries sorted by the keys, not the values. In your case it's using the natural order of `String`s.

If you want a `Map` to maintain the order of insertion, use a `LinkedHashMap`. If you do this you will need to change the return type to `Map<String, Integer>`.

I can't write detailed code as I am unclear about the types of some of your variables, but the basic steps are:

1. Sort the `List` `keywords` based on the `value` field.
2. `Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();`
3. Iterate over the first `n` items in `keywords` and populate `map`. Because you are using a `LinkedHashMap` the entries will stay in the right order.
4. `return map;`

Comment: Incisive. The problem is when I assign keywords=keywords.sort{...}, keywords became sorted by the key again due to the nature of TreeMap! After I changed it to LinkedHashMap things went back as planned!

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `entrySet()` from the sorted map, which behaves more or less like a list, and get a range from it:

```
def getKeywords(Map keywords, int itensQty){
    def sorted=keywords.sort{ a, b ->
        b.value <=> a.value;
    }
    sorted.entrySet().toList()[0..<itensQty]
}


keywords = ["a": 90, "b": 110, "c": 70, "d": 130]

assert getKeywords(keywords, 2) == ["d": 130, "b": 110].entrySet().toList()
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it - slightly simpler: `keywords.entrySet().sort { -it.value }[0..<n]`

Comment: This is a neat solution. What a pity I cannot accept both two answers for the same thread!

Answer (score 1):

As from your code it seems you are using groovy, here is how you can do it in groovy using a `for loop`

```
    TreeMap<String,Integer> result = new TreeMap<>()
    for(def entry : keywords) {
        result[entry.key] = entry.value

        n--
        if(n == 0)
            break
    }

    return result
```